# Is it safe to drive with broken wheel lug nut.?

Tags: lug-nut, vitz

My Vitz front wheel lug nut broke. I need to drive to garage 4km. How safe is this? What should I pay attention for while driving ?

Comment: How / why did it fail?

Comment: I replaced the Tyre. For more safety I tried to harden it more. Then the lug nut broke.

Comment: The concern is that the others may also be weakened. I would advise replacing all of the studs on that wheel, and have the  mechanic check the torque on all the rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should not be an issue driving with one lug missing, as long as the other lug nuts are torqued as they are supposed to be. 4km is not a long distance, and especially one you shouldn't be worried about. It would behoove you to get it replaced as soon as possible to prevent further issues, though. As long as you aren't speeding or taking corners at high speeds, there shouldn't be any issues or anything you'd be looking for as you will probably not even notice any difference in driving the vehicle.

Comment: Good answer.    No rally driving until fixed.

Comment: Replaced all 4 wheel studs as suggested. No problem occurred while driving to the garage.